# Sending cookie with subkey with webclient

Tags: c#, cookies, webclient

I am trying to access a web page with `WebClient` class. The page `login` with `cookies`, so in order to login and managed cookies with `WebClient` I used this code (downloaded from web)

```
public class WebClientCookie : WebClient
{      
     private CookieContainer _cookies;
     public WebClientCookie(CookieContainer cookies)
     {
         _cookies = cookies;
     }

     protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
     {
         HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)base.GetWebRequest(address);
         request.CookieContainer = _cookies;
         return request;
     }        
}
```

When I access the page with a browser, when it post login data the server return cookies like this

> cookieMemo=UserCotizacion=False&UserID=7128&UsuarioLogeado=DOMIZI2282&IdUsuarioLogueado=7128&PERSONIF=N&FechaUltLoginAdministrativo=00:00:00
>   a.m.&Nombre=DOMIZI,JOSEFERNANDO&EmailPersona=fedomizi@hotmail.com&userPersonif=DOMIZI,JOSEFERNANDO-2316992251&cuit=2316992251;
>   path=/

and in the next request it sends cookie like this
[cookie send by browser in next request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMNx3.png)

When I try to login with the `WebClient` I get the same `cookie` but when I do the next request the `cookie` is sent wrong.. (at least not as the browser)
[how webclient sends the cookie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmO3R.png)

Comment: What would you like the server to respond with?  I'm not totally sure what the problem is here that you'd like help with.

Comment: it seems the application page which you are trying to access is creating JWT token which is stored in the form of cookie. This Token changes each time a user logs in. That might be the reason each time you are sending a request you are getting cookie differently